# Form doesn't have access to its values. Is this normal?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

This is the first time I notice this and it's surprised me a bit.

I have a zend_form with a simple text element.

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('Name');
$this->addElement($name);
```

The strange thing is that when I submit the form and try to read the value in the form itself (I'm doing some debugging there not in the controller), `$name->getValue()` doesn't work but the direct $_POST works.

```
echo $name->getValue(); //gives blank
echo $_POST['name'];    //gives the right value
```

Is this normal? How does the form not have its values? I thought it's better to read them with $field->getValue() than to access the $_POST values directly.

The second question is, to read the value in the form, is there a better way than accessing directly from $_POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the data explicitly to the form, because ZF has no idea where to get it from:

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST)) { // access values }
```

or

```
if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) { // access values }
```

Comment: This works. But really how is it possible that the form doesn't have access to its values? It needs those values to give to validators and filters. Actually what I'm doing is passing values to a custom filter. I thought the filter would automatically get the $value from the field it's been added to, but that doesn't work, so I'm passing the $value myself to the filter. Of course it would be easier if the form can read its own values, then I can pass it directly without involving the controller at all. I may post another question about the filter. It may be I'm doing something wrong there too.

Comment: "But really how is it possible that the form doesn't have access to its values" --- it does have an access to the data you've passed, in explicit manner. ZF cannot predict where to take data from: $_POST, $_GET or even fetch it from the file.

Comment: So I'm curious, I could explicitly pass the value to the form after the if validation. But what if I bypassed this and accessed it directly from $_POST. Is that bad, does it have some disadvantages? Notice that I'm giving this data to a filter which will modify it slightly, so it's not that I'm using that input directly to the screen or anything similar.

Comment: @jblue: I think it is bad. I think that if you use zend form, then you should use regular ZF Forms workflow: pass the data - validate/filter them - extract the data from form. You should not rely on the source of the data all across the code, instead ZF provide you a chance to reference to $_POST once (on the passing to `isValid()` stage) and after that you don't care about the datasource.

Comment: @jdblue: If you need some element value _before_ it gets filtered, then it sounds like the filter should be removed from the form element and applied as a one-off, _after_ you have done `isValid($data)` and `getValues()`. Alternatively, if you really need to know the unfiltered value, you can get it from `$request->getPost()->myelement`. But I'm inclined to stick to the standard `isValid()` and `getValues()` flow.

Answer (score 1):

No. Stick to using `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Honestly I don't see why you're using Zend to create and fetch data from a form, when it's much easier to do this with straight PHP.

```
<?php if( !isset( $_POST['name'] ) ): ?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</form>
<?php else: ?>
Value = <?= $_POST['name'] ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

I guess it's all in your style of coding. I would prefer the above, but if you want to separate logic from HTML, then Zend is certainly an option.

Comment: Because zend form performs additional validations and filters. Also - you forgot to implement values restoring if form was invalid.

Comment: @zerkms Point taken. I was a bit blunt about my opposition to the Zend framework. :)

Comment: +1 to @PhpMyCoder on a gentlemanly backdown. Disclosure: I'm a big ZF fan. ;-)

Comment: I totally understand. I guess I'm more of a DIY guy. It's easier for me if I understand the inner-workings! :D